# Replace text between tags span in html with c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to replace text between `<span>` tags from an HTML document. I have the following code:

```
string pattern = "<span class=\"nameLastname\">(.*)</span>";
string nameLastnamePattern = "<span class=\"nameLastname\">"+name+ lastname+"</span>";

System.IO.StreamReader objReader;
objReader = new StreamReader(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\intel\\main.html");
string content = objReader.ReadToEnd();
objReader.Close();

content = Regex.Replace(content,pattern, nameLastnamePattern);

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\intel\\main.html");
writer.Write(content);
writer.Close();
```

For example, I want to replace  `<span class="nameLastname">George</span>` with something like `<span class="nameLastname">Dave</span>`. But my code doesn't work.

Comment: Regex and Html don't play well together. Html Agility Pack is your friend, https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: I think your pattern contains more Regex specific characters besides ". I always use Notepad++ find/replace function to quickly validate regex patterns.

Try "<span class\=\"nameLastname\">([A-Za-z ]*)</span>"

Comment: You can use an online tester too. http://regexstorm.net/tester or http://regexhero.net/tester

Answer (score 0):

[Working example on Rextester.](http://rextester.com/PBL41136)

Pattern: `@"<span([^>]*)class=\""(\w+)\""([^>]*)>(.*)<\/span>"`

```
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
regex.Replace (inputData, "<span${1}class=\"${2}\"${3}>Replacement</span>")
```

First group captures content *before* the `class` attribute. Second group captures the *class name*. Third group captures attributes *after* class. The fourth group is the actual span node *element content*. That gets replaced.

Comment: In Pattern, when I want to replace span which class=lastname. What I should write ? @"<span([^>]*)class=\""lastname\""([^>]*)>(.*)<\/span>"  ?

Comment: I want to change in Html document user datas, such as name, lastname, mobile, age.  . For example: age is in <span class=age>Age</span>  . Mobile is in <span class=mobile>231231</span>.  For them how would Pattern like ?

Comment: It's in the answer. 2nd group captures the class name. You can switch by it. This is a new question by the way ...

Comment: so when I want to Replace value of lastname, I have to write: Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
regex.Replace (inputData, "<span class=\"mobile\"}>"+324123123+"</span>")  ?